# Create new screen with correct environment and at pwd

Tags: bash, mac, unix, gnu-screen

It's been brought to my attention from my users that the screen command can be made a little easier to use. Initially, calling screen creates a fresh bash environment at the pwd of wherever the user used the command.

I then did some digging and made a .screenrc file containing:

**.screenrc**

```
shell -$SHELL
```

and this executes a login script. Now, the proper environment is loaded, but the user has been misplaced to the home directory! I want both of these to be true on startup.

19.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the help of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29415161/how-can-i-change-default-directory-in-screen-when-i-have-defshell-set-to-bash#comment47041502_29424172).

**.screenrc**

```
shell $SHELL
```

Notice the lack of `-` as it was before. This makes it not a login script and simply sets the shell, I believe. So this is the first half, and allows screen to start at your pwd. Then, I made a .bashrc script:

**.bashrc**

```
source /User/username/.bash_profile
```

This allowed for the correct environment to be pulled by default.

And that's it! Two lines and two files to solve my problem. I hope this helps the next person in any way.